# Android WiFi-Direct Connection and Broadcast

Tags: android, connection, broadcast, wifi-direct

1) How long does it take an Android device to set up a WiFi-Direct connection with another Android device? 
I read some news from GM, they are developing something system with WiFi-Direct, they claims that they can connect in about 1 second. (But they are not working with Android phone).
From the Android SDK, WiFi-Direct works very similar to Bluetooth: discovery, pair, connect....

I want to know how fast can the devices be connected (from discovering to connection established) on Android phones.

2) Is it possible to broadcast with WiFi-Direct? E.g. Device A has WiFi-Direct connected with Device B,C,D,E and it wants to broadcast some information.

I don't have WiFi Direct enabled devices in hand, just want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

yes.It can broadcast if it acts as a group owner.for example in your case if A acts as Group owner,it will brodcast data to B,C,D,E.
now if you are wondering what is group owner then
devices with WIFI direct form a group when they connect and one device out of group acts as groupowner.